# Makeprg runs in different directory than `pwd`

Tags: makeprg, make

When I run a command using `make`, it runs from a different directory than running it as a regular command with `!`. My app is a [CBRA](https://cbra.info/), and I open vim from within a component. The top-level app, though, is where the git repository is rooted.

Running `:pwd` returns `/Users/bill/dev/app/components/my_component`.

Running `:!pwd` returns `/Users/bill/dev/app/components/my_component`.

Running `:set makeprg=pwd` followed by `:make` returns `/Users/bill/dev/app`.

I'd like to run my `make` commands from within my pwd, preferably without having to prepend a `cd` to everything.

The only related configuration I could find is `autochdir`, which is set to `noautochdir`.

Comment: My best guess is that there is a `QuickFixCmdPre` autocmd event; you can check with `:au QuickFixCmdPre`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Have you tried [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)?

Comment: Huge apologies; the issue was happening in neovim, but I tried it as well in an old installation of vim and got the same behavior. I forgot that, once upon a time, that old vim was my daily driver, and the same plugin ([vim-rails](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) in this case) was installed for both. @MartinTournoij there was indeed an autocmd for this action.

Comment: [vim-rails](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/blob/0c4f91dcba7da0a1003469cbfd477e98322d9f1e/autoload/rails.vim#L1242-L1261) seems to change directory, but to be honest I don't really understand why or what to exactly.